# Efficiently perform cheap calculations on many (1e6-1e10) combinations of rows in a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, combinations

I need to perform some simple calculations on a large number of combinations of rows or columns for a pandas dataframe. I need to figure out how to do so most efficiently because the number of combinations might go up above a billion.

The basic approach is easy--just performing means, comparison operators, and sums on subselections of a dataframe. But the only way I've figured out involves doing a loop over the combinations, which isn't very pythonic and isn't super efficient. Since efficiency will matter as the number of samples goes up I'm hoping there might be some smarter way to do this.

Right now I am building the list of combinations and then selecting those rows and doing the calculations using built-in pandas tools (see pseudo-code below). One possibility is to parallelize this, which should be pretty easy. However, I wonder if I'm missing a deeper way to do this more efficiently.

A few thoughts, ordered from big to small:

1. Is there some smart pandas/python or even some smart linear algebra way to do this? I haven't figured such out, but want to check.
2. Is the best approach to stick with pandas? Or convert to a numpy array and just do everything using numeric indices there, and then convert back to easier-to-understand data-frames?
3. Is the built-in mean() the best approach, or should I use some kind of apply()?
4. Is it faster to select rows or columns in any way? The matrix is symmetric so it's easy to grab either.
5. I'm currently actually selecting 18 rows because each of the 6 rows actually has three entries with slightly different parameters--I could combine those into individual rows beforehand if it's faster to select 6 rows than 18 for some reason.

Here's a rough-sketch of what I'm doing:

```
from itertools import combinations

df = from_excel() #Test case is 30 rows & cols
df = df.set_index('Col1') # Column and row 1 are names, rest are the actual matrix values

allSets = combinations(df.columns, 6)

temp = []
for s in allSets:
    
    avg1 = df.loc[list(s)].mean().mean()
    cnt1 = df.loc[list(s)].gt(0).sum().sum()
    
    temp.append([s,avg1,cnt1])

dfOut = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=['Set','Average','Count'])
```

Comment: For starters, don't do `allSets = list(combinations(df.columns, 6))`, just use `allSets = combinations(df.columns, 6)`, why did you use `list`?

Comment: Eh -- I think that's leftover from some tries to pass the full list of sets, rather than one at a time--I need list(s) in the loop so that the dataframe is passed a list. Corrected here.

Comment: Anyway, you can cache `df.mean()` and `df.gt(0).sum()` since you will end up re-calculating that for each combination, which is pretty wasteful. Note, for loops aren't unpythonic at all, **for loops are very pythonic**, especially using `itertools`, which there is no better way to get the combinations in pure python. (Looping over pandas dataframes is slow, but that's only an issue if your operations are vectorizable, which combinations are not)

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't notice the opportunity to cache those, but that sped it up  by >30%! And thanks for the comment regarding loops being pythonic--I was looking for a way to have things more vectorized, but it makes sense that's the best way to do it since the combinations aren't vectorizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few general considerations that should help:

1. Not that I know of, though the best place to ask is on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [Math Professionals](https://mathoverflow.com). And it is worth a try. There may be a better way to frame the question if you are doing something very specific with the results - looking for minimum/maximum, etc.
2. In general, you are right, that `pandas`, as a layer on top of `NumPy` is probably not the speeding things up. However, most of the heavy-lifting is done at the level of `NumPy`, and until you are sure `pandas` is to blame, use it.
3. `mean` is better than your own function applied across rows or columns because it uses C implementation of mean in `NumPy` under the hood which is always going to be faster than Python.
4. Given that `pandas` is organizing data in column fashion (i.e. each column is a contiguous `NumPy` array), it is better to go row-wise.
5. It would be great to see an example of data here.

Now, some comments on the code:

- use `iloc` and numeric indices instead of `loc` - it is way faster
- it is unnecessary to turn tuples into list here: `df.loc[list(s)].gt(0).sum().sum()`
  just use:  `df.loc[s].gt(0).sum().sum()`
- you should rather use a generator instead of the `for` loop where you append elements to a temporary list (this is awfully slow and unnecessary, because you are creating pandas dataframe either way). Also, use tuples instead of lists wherever possible for maximum speed:

```py
    def gen_fun():
       allSets = combinations(df.columns, 6)
       for s in allSets:
          avg1 = df.loc[list(s)].mean().mean()
          cnt1 = df.loc[list(s)].gt(0).sum().sum()
    
          yield (s, avg1, cnt1)
    
    dfOut = pd.DataFrame(gen_fun(), columns=['Set', 'Average', 'Count'])
```

- Another thing is, that you can preprocess the dataframe to use only values that are positive to avoid `gt(0)` operation in each loop.

In this way you are sparing both memory and CPU time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your really complete thoughts on this. Really appreciate it! A couple of comments:
1. Thanks for the explanation for the generator--that was helpful and gave a little bit of a speedup. 
2. I have not been able to use the tuples to index for the rows/columns -- I get an error: "Too many indexers"
3. As above, thanks for the thought on cacheing -- that's a big speedup. 
4. I'm going to work on building a way to use .iloc rather that .loc--I'll give an update later. 
Thanks!

Comment: My bad about indexing with tuples. Tuples are used for MultiIndex indexing (each position for a different level of the index). I forgot about it and hence the issue.

Comment: No problem--totally understand those details can be tricky. :) 
I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation. But I did accept it.